# Files not saved on Ubuntu instance using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have just migrated a project to AWS on an Ubuntu instance.

It is a PHP backoffice project.

I am able to work with the MySQL database, and I am able to upload files using Filezilla.
My issue is that I am trying to save files to `usuarios` folder on  the instance using this PHP file:

```
<?php 



 if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"]=="form1")){
$length = 6;

$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

$prefijo =  $randomString;
    

    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    
    $file_upload = "true";
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']>2000000){
$file_upload="false";
}
    
    if ($file_upload == 'true'){
    
   $str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $nombre_archivo);
   $str =preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"usuarios/".$prefijo.$str);
    ?>
      <script>

    window.opener.document.getElementById("imagen").value="<?php echo $prefijo.$str;?>";
     

    
    self.close();

    </script>
<?php
    
    }
    else 
    {
        $texto = $lang['LIMIT_FILE'];
        echo $texto."<BR><BR><BR>";?>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Reintentar' onClick="window.location.reload()" />
    
    
<?php }
    ?>

  

    

    <?php 

}

else {?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="subirfoto.php" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p>

    <input name="userfile" type="file" />

  </p>

  <p>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Picture" />

    <input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="form1" />

  </p>


</form>

<?php }?>
```

but the files are not saved on the folder.

I guess it may be an issue of folder permissions.

The project is working fine on another web server but not on this Ubuntu instance on AWS.

What should I check and change in order to save files on that server folder?

Comment: XHTML is an odd choice for 2020 … and an even odder one since your XHTML isn't valid.

Comment: @Quentin, it is an old PHP script, do you mind that's the problem?

Comment: @Quentin, I have just removed all html parts of the script, and the issue is there, anything changed, but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, it was a matter of permissions.

I have executed following commands and the issue is solved:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:ubuntu /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```